# Is there a way to get the Parent components name/displayName from within a Child component?

Tags: reactjs

Long story short, I'm looking to make some error handling more descriptive (like propType validation errors), and was wondering if there's a way to get the name of the parent component doing the boo boo.

For example, the propType validation errors read like so:

> Warning: Failed propType: Invalid prop 'label' of type 'number'
>   supplied to 'MyChild', expected 'string'. Check the render method of
>   'MyParent'.

I'd like my own error to have the parent in it, reading something like:

> Error: Instantiation of abstract class 'AbstractMyClass' is not allowed. Check the render method of 'MyParent'.

Is this possible?
If it makes a difference, these are written in ES6 syntax.

Thanks in advance!
-Ted

Answer (score 2):

You can get the name of `function A() {}` with `A.name`, if `function B() {}` inherits from `A` then `Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype`,  prototypes should have a link to the constructor through the `constructor` property i.e. `A.protoype.constructor === A`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class AbstractClass extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    if (this.constructor === AbstractClass) {
      throw Error('Instantiation of abstract class AbstractMyClass is not allowed')
    }
  }

  getSuperName () {
    var proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(this) // or this.constructor.prototype
    return Object.getPrototypeOf(proto).constructor.name
  }
}

class A extends AbstractClass {}
class B extends A {}

console.log(new A())                  // works
console.log(new A().getSuperName())   // AbstractMyClass
console.log(new B().getSuperName())   // A

console.log(new AbstractClass())    // throws error
```

Test it online at http://esnextb.in/?gist=ff5fc627922285b3d085bd9c42420736

Comment: Upvoted for some really useful info in there, but it's not the name of the super that's being extended that I'm looking for, it's the parent (or owner?) that is rendering it--like the proptypes error does. For example in a root app component that includes the class and tries to render it to the dom--what's the name of the component rendering it (like 'check the render method of 'MyAppRoot'. I hope i'm explaining that well enough.